# How can I start newpage after using tikz to create page border line?

Tags: tikz-styles

I have created front page of paper with border line around the paper. But the problem is like the image below[image: I want to start "Part A (10 marks at new page)]. I hope any one can help me. Thank you!

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4]{crop}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=1pt,rounded corners=0pt,]
      ($ (current page.north west) + (1cm,1cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) $);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
\hspace{2.5cm} \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{upm.png}
\newline
\newline
\newline
\begin{center}
\titlepage \bfseries FAKULTI SAINS \\ \vspace{1cm} Peperiksaan Akhir \\  Semester Kedua 2013/2014 \\


\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{23mm}@{:}m{12.3cm}}
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
KURSUS  &   STATISTIK BAGI SAINS GUNAAN \\
KOD     &   MTH3003 \\  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\hline
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
PROGRAM & BS(K) \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
TARIKH     & 20 JUN 2014 \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
MASA          & 8.30-10.30 PAGI \hfill JANGKAMASA \hfill : 2 JAM \\

\end{tabular}\\
\vspace{0.8cm}

\begin{flushleft}
ARAHAN KEPADA CALON:
\mdseries   \begin{enumerate}
        \item  Jawab Semua Soalan \newline \textit{Answer all question}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{flushleft}

\bfseries
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{23mm}@{:}m{5cm}m{30mm}@{:}m{5cm}}
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{}\\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{SLIP KEHADIRAN}\\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{}\\
No. Matrik & &Program & \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
No. Meja   & & Tandatangan &\\
\end{tabular}
\\
\vspace{2cm}
\mdseries 
Kertas soalan ini mengandungi 14 halaman tidak termasuk helaian pertama\\
\vspace{4.5cm}
Hak Cipta Terpelihara UPM \\
\end{center}
\end{center}
\end{center}



\textbf{Part A (10 marks)}
\begin{questions}

\question

A test of the breaking strengths of two different types of cables was conducted using samples of \\
$n_1 = n_2 = 100$

\end{questions}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a complete code example demonstrating the problem  (a [minimal working example, or MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228))?

Comment: After `\maketitle` try `\newpage`.

Comment: sorry, i'm a newbie in using LaTeX plus a newbie in this website. Sorry for my shortage.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround. `Exam` class has an `\begin/\end{coverpages}` environment that can be utilized.  Therefore, this solution marks out `\begin/\end{figure}` and `\titlepage`.
Note: remove the `demo`in the `graphicx` option for real implementation.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{exam}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % remove demo for real case implementation
\usepackage[a4]{crop}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
\begin{coverpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=1pt,rounded corners=0pt,]
      ($ (current page.north west) + (1cm,1cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) $);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
\hspace{2.5cm} \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{upm.png}
\newline
\newline
\newline
\begin{center}
%\titlepage 
\bfseries FAKULTI SAINS \\ \vspace{1cm} Peperiksaan Akhir \\  Semester Kedua 2013/2014 \\

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{23mm}@{:}m{12.3cm}}
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
KURSUS  &   STATISTIK BAGI SAINS GUNAAN \\
KOD     &   MTH3003 \\  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\hline
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
PROGRAM & BS(K) \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
TARIKH     & 20 JUN 2014 \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
MASA          & 8.30-10.30 PAGI \hfill JANGKAMASA \hfill : 2 JAM \\

\end{tabular}\\
\vspace{0.8cm}

\begin{flushleft}
ARAHAN KEPADA CALON:
\mdseries   \begin{enumerate}
        \item  Jawab Semua Soalan \newline \textit{Answer all question}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{flushleft}

\bfseries
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{23mm}@{:}m{5cm}m{30mm}@{:}m{5cm}}
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{}\\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{SLIP KEHADIRAN}\\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{}\\
No. Matrik & &Program & \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
No. Meja   & & Tandatangan &
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}             % adjust this parameter
\mdseries 
Kertas soalan ini mengandungi 14 halaman tidak termasuk helaian pertama

\vspace{1cm}             % adjust this parameter
Hak Cipta Terpelihara UPM 

\end{center}
\end{center}
\end{center}
\end{coverpages}

\textbf{Part A (10 marks)}
\begin{questions}

\question

A test of the breaking strengths of two different types of cables was conducted using samples of \\
$n_1 = n_2 = 100$

\end{questions}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are certainly welcome.

Comment: i didn'tfind the fullpage package. can i use fullpict instead?

Comment: Hi, use Google to search fullpage, CTAN has it. or google search fullpage.sty such as this link `http://www.kovrik.com/sib/russify/tex-latex/ams_cyrillic/fullpage.sty` then save it in your current working directory should work. Hmmmmm .. fullpic won't work (I don't known this package).